# XPath not returning anything when asked for table tag

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract table values from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denisemauldin/immer/master/index.html but it returns nothing. Am I doing something wrong or something else?

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page=requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denisemauldin/immer/master/index.html')
tree=html.fromstring(page.content)
print(tree.xpath('//table'))
```

it returns []

Comment: If proper quotes are used, this _does_ return a table element.

Comment: @MathiasMüller its returning empty

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1am1EiakVAjnlh_H6fKV-yGKpZqHYSpsT

Comment: I got this ``table`` element.

Comment: The number 1 reasons XPath expressions don't work as expected is that you've ignored the fact that the elements are in a namespace, in this case the XHTML namespace. Because so many people fall into this trap I shall close it as a duplicate; search for "XPath default namespace" to find hundreds of similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, very close. What you need to understand is that in order to extract the text, you need to tell XPath exactly how it should traverse the tree and extract the information. From your code, you are only telling it to traverse up to `table` node and the output that you get `[<Element table at 0x794c120>]` is correct since that's the address of that element.

The following code is explicit and will traverse up to the given tag and get the text of the element using `text()`.

```py
from lxml import html
import requests
page=requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denisemauldin/immer/master/index.html')
tree=html.fromstring(page.content)
print(tree.xpath('//table/tr/td/text()')) # ['immer', 'R Documentation']
```

You should consider using HTML parsers such as 'Beautiful Soup'. You can read more on that [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: This is not what the question is about. The OP states that they get an empty list as a return value if the XPath expression is `//table`.